# Matching via sizes to trace widths

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, electromagnetism, theory, via

Let's say I've determined a trace width (\$t_w\$) for a trace, and now I want to determine the size of a via on that trace.

My intuition is that to maintain the same amount of copper as the trace through the via (and assuming the plating inside the hole has the same thickness as traces do), then the via's minimum drill diameter (\$⌀_{min}\$) should be chosen such that its ​circumference is at least the trace width, and the minimum annular ring (\$r_{min}\$) should be at least half the trace width. I.e., given \$t_w\$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
⌀_{min} = \frac{t_w}{\pi} \\ \\
r_{min} = \frac{t_w}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

The total diameter being at least \$⌀_{min} + 2\times r_{min}\$.

So, if I have a 24 mil trace, then \$⌀_{min}\approx\$ 7.64 mil and \$r_{min}=\$ 12 mil.

However; vias are cylindrical, and physics is confusing. So my question is: **Am I on the right track and, if so, do I theoretically have to make extra allowances (especially in \$⌀_{min}\$) to account for things like capacitance, inductance, and other EM effects inside the via hole?** Is it different for power vs. signal traces? Are there *maximum* dimensions where weird things start happening?

Comment: Usually the answer for anything that actually starts requiring this is "ask your board house".

Comment: Well, I didn't state it but yeah there's an underlying assumption that the chosen via size also needs to meet fabrication specs.

Comment: Not just "meets specs", although that's obviously a prereq. Some board houses also already have this sort of thing characterized, or can at least suggest a starting point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I on the right track

You are on the right track.

However, the track may be 100's of mm long while the via is probably only 2 mm or less. You may be able to live with a small localized resistance at the point of the via.

You might also rather use multiple small vias in parallel rather than one big via to carry a large current.

> do I theoretically have in make extra allowances (especially in ⌀min) to account for things like capicitance, inductance, and other EM effects inside the via hole?

It's fairly rare to need to worry about both high current effects (which would drive a high via diameter to avoid over-heating) and electromagnetic effects.

If you are running high current through the via, size the via to achieve an acceptable resistance and acceptable self-heating.

If you are running RF signals (above maybe 700 MHz) through the via, size the via and its pads and anti-pads to maintain close to the desired characteristic impedance  through the via structure.

If you are running RF at high enough power to worry about self-heating, then you have a bigger challenge. You will notice that many high-power RF circuits avoid vias altogether. They also use ceramic (alumina, for example) substrates rather than fiberglass to improve thermal conductivity.

> Are there maximum dimensions where weird things start happening?

For power? No, not really. It's common to just use a split plane rather than a track to carry high current power nets.

For RF signals? Yes, a too-wide track won't meet the characteristic impedance requirements. Even if you move the reference plane away to meet the characteristic impedance requirement you might end up with a multi-mode transmission line, which would cause signal distortion and/or radiation loss.

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you, really appreciate the amount of interesting info and research points packed in here. 

Comment: "size the via and its pads and anti-pads to maintain close to the desired characteristic impedance through the via structure.", how is that done without using 3D solvers and expensive EM field simulation tools?